The standard parts used on STC projects should be Indicated conform to FAR regulations？
The standard sleeve accept by Boeing SWPM, it conform to "AMS-DTL-23053/5 class 1".
However, when we use this product in STC project, we are required to prove that it meets FAR25.853(a) by DER.
Have you ever encountered a similar situation? What is the accreditation procedure of standard parts in STC project?
